# Migrating Ubuntu vm from Google Cloud to Azure

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform

I would like to migrate an Ubuntu VM from google cloud platform(GCP) to Azure. I did a lot of research but couldn't find an easy way to do it.

One approach mentioned creating an image of the GCP VM, downloading and uploading it to Azure and then creating a new VM on Azure using that image. I was able to create the GCP image but after that, I couldn't find a way to upload it to Azure and create a new VM there using that image.

Can you please help on how to do it? Or if you have any other way to migrate from GCP to Azure please suggest that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SO is for programming questions. SuperUser is for server / infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest path to move a single VM as you are trying to do might be to simply download the VHD from Google and then upload it to Azure.

Here is how I would go about it:

1) Download the VHD from Google Cloud

2) Spin up the VM in local Hyper-V

3) [Prepare the VHD for Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/create-upload-ubuntu)

4) [Upload the VHD to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd#option-1-upload-a-vhd)

5) Build the VM from the specialized uploaded disk

Comment: The links in point 4 & 5 are for windows VM. I am trying to do this for an Ubuntu VM. I do have the VHD file downloaded, so now I need to prepare the VHD for Azure and upload it? I would appreciate if you can share similar links for Ubuntu VM. Thanks!

Comment: @shantanuSpark I fixed the links.